# merge several plots in one column without any space between them

Tags: plotting

We have three plots (The relation of plots are as `Plot[Sin[x](*or Cos[x] or Tan[x]*), {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{{-1, 0, 1}, None}, {{0, Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, None}}, FrameTicksStyle -> Thick]`)

[image]

and

[image]

and

[image]

How can we combine above three plots as below format: (We wish the space between plots in a vertical column be vanished.)

[image]

Comment: thanks, Because I could not know the keywords I cold not find that answer